# How to make array values consecutive but remain in the right order?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I have an **dynamic array** that could for example look like this:

```
$arr = array(42, 30, 70, 10);
```

I have a function called `CreateOrder`  and I want it to return an array like this

```
function createOrder($array)
{

    /* 
    This function should return an array starting at 0,
    while keeping the correct order, like this:
    */

    $new_array = array(2, 1, 3, 0);

}
```

I have been trying and trying with foreach loops but I can't get my head around it.

Any help appreciated,

Nathan

Comment: what is the logic behind the given example and the output

Comment: `array_unshift($arr, 0)` ?

Comment: Do you need the positions of the elements to be returned if the array was sorted?

Comment: So you want to change the order but also keep the order, that doesn't make sense. You want to start with `0` but your example doesn't start with `0`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I meant consecutive as in a way of 0-x with no missing numbers. (e.g. 3-5-4-1-0-2 and not 42-30-70-28-12) so basically I wanted to get an array of the positions of the numbers in the original array. Mark Baker answered my question as I needed 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the order of the original array being trashed in the process:

```
asort($arr);
$new_array = array_combine(array_keys($arr), range(0,count($arr)-1));
ksort($new_array);
```

Not so bad inside a function, because that uses a copy of the original array unless you pass by reference, so only the order of the locally-function-scoped copy gets trashed

Or even more simply:

```
asort($arr);
$new_array = array_keys($arr);
asort($new_array);
$newArr = array_keys($new_array);
```

Comment: Awesome! The first piece of code works! The second one returns something else though! Thank you :-)

Comment: Yeah, my bad.... I missed a couple of lines when I was copy/pasting the second, edited them in now

Comment: Ah, the seconds one works too. Did a performance test and the second one was +/- 0.4 times faster. Will choose that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the asort() function will fit your needs:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.asort.php

Don't forget to pass your array by reference, so this has to be called as is (without an assignment).

Answer (score 0):

- Clone the array.
- Sort the cloned array in ascending order.
- For each element in the original array search for key in sorted array, and insert the returned position in the new array.
- return the position array.

Following code will help

```
function createOrder($array){
    $cloneArray = asort($array);
    $positionArray = []; 

    foreach($cloneArray as $element){
       $positionArray[] = array_search($element,$array);
    }  

    return $positionArray; 
}
```